# Prevent Eclipse from collapsing a path in project explorer that I manually opened?

Tags: eclipse

This is about a peculiar habit of the Project Explorer in Eclipse that has been bugging me for years now.

If I expand some source subtree somewhere among my projects and then have to re-think which file I actually need to open, I often switch back into some other part of my project tree to find the info I need.

But, more often than not, when I actually did find that info and know which file exactly I need to open, the source tree I have expanded earlier has been collapsed again by eclipse (probably because it decided that it has to do a quick workspace rebuild or gradle refresh or something in that vein). Even worse, sometimes eclipse reorders the submodules of the (maven/gradle) project so that the subtree I have expanded earlier isn't at the same position in the project explorer anymore and I need to go looking for it again. Eclipse sometimes even (apparently randomly) starts to reorder the tree in the moment just before I want to click on a file or something like that.

So. How can I configure Eclipse to never collapse a subtree in the project explorer that I expanded manually? And how can I prevent Eclipse from reordering the projects? (Switching the IDE is out of question for this particular project, because there are some eclipse-only plugins for the framework involved.)

Comment: You need to work out in more detail when this happens, because I have never seen project explorer do this.

Comment: @greg-449 I noticed that for years and never found any trigger event for that... the best I can identify would be "I clicked on a file in a different module than I was just working in". It might only come up in bigger gradle/maven projects with >10 (sub-)modules.

Comment: I do not know or have heard of such behaviour either. It might be caused by a plug-in you installed.

Comment: @howlger Then the only explanation I can see would be that the framework plugins (eclipse + Liferay Plugins = "Liferay Developer Studio"; it's even available prepackaged as a bundle) are responsible. I use eclipse only for projects involving that framework, so that would actually explain why I never found anything on the net regarding that behaviour of eclipse. Gnarf. I was hoping for a completely simple option that I just didn't see in the last 8 years...

Comment: Maybe and maybe there is also a simple Liferay option for that. If you work the way you describe, using [Mylyn](https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) might be helpfull.

Comment: @howlger Just from the description of mylyn I don't see how it would help me... I mean, how should mylyn know that the `resource/path/with/package/and/subdirs/view.jsp` file in one module is the view template override to the beans controlled by `EnterpriseyLongNamedServiceUtil` that is used in another module (and defined in a third)? Association problems like this are the source of me having to look through module trees and I don't see how any tool could help me there :/ (It might as well be that I'm misunderstanding what you're getting at ;)

Comment: @orithena Mylyn can remember the context (things you have viewed and edited) and hide everything else for a less crowded _Package Explorer_. So Mylyn doesn't help to find something, but to find it again. The context refers to a task. If you do something else in between, you change the task and can continue where you left off before.

Comment: @howlger Okay, I can see how that might help, thanks... let's see if I can work with that workflow :)